# RewriteRule to keep domain and change subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have multiple domains pointing to the same webserver directory.
Im looking for a RewriteRule which redirects the user to a subfolder when a specific URL is entered. But the domain has to stay the same.

What i need:

```
    www.domain1.de/special
    should redirect the user to:
    www.domain1.de/redirect/special.php

    www.domain2.de/special
    should redirect the user to:
    www.domain2.de/redirect/special.php
```

Usually i do redirects like this with:

```
Redirect /special http://www.domain1.de/redirects/special.php
```

But this solution doesnt work with 2 different domains because you will always end up at domain1.de

I tried a lot of different solutions. Simple example:

```
RewriteRule http://www.domain1.de/special http://www.domain1.de/redirect/special.php
RewriteRule http://www.domain2.de/special http://www.domain2.de/redirect/special.php
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)domain1.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^special/ http://domain1.de/redirects/special.php [R=301,L]
```

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
RewriteRule ^/?special(.*)$ /redirect/special.php$1 [R=302,L]
```